# How to implement horizontal navigation through multiple wordpress posts with dynamic content (slideshow-like)?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, slideshow

My client wants a page where one can navigate through all the available Wordpress auctions (I'm using the Auction Plugin by Sitemile). You can see how the page in question looks like [here](http://standcardeira.com/leiloes/zona-exclusiva/).

I'm using a table inside a div where each table column refers to a single post/auction. Every column must be 1366px wide, and the navigation through columns/posts should be made clicking the left and right yellow arrows. Is it possible? If so, how?

Or is there a better way to do this, not using a table but divs only?

Here's how I'm generating the content:

```
<div class="box_content">
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php $i = 0; if ($pageposts): ?>
            <?php global $post; ?>
                <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        <?php echo "<td style='min-width: 1366px; padding-right: 60px;'>
                        (... auction content ...)
                        "?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use a slider library of some sort. Just search google for 'javascript slider'.

Comment: All the slider libraries I see on the web seem to work only with images or fixed content, not with a complex and dynamic page like the one I need. If anyone knows of any library which would be suitable for my case, I'll be glad to hear about it :)